# AppStats for managed VMs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-managed-vm

We were running on AppEngine but recently moved over to Managed VMs. For some reason AppStats is no longer available? We just get a 404 not found error when browsing to our appstats URL. Is appstats not supported on Managad VMs? If not, is there a way of isolating poorly performing endpoints within our application?

Comment: Have you tried [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/)?  Since Managed VMs work in a different way (as Compute Engine VMs), it's probably trickier for Google to wire up Appstats/Cloud Trace to apps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to isolate poorly performing endpoints is to use the advanced filter search in the GCP Logs Viewer.  It is a little hard to find at first.

To get there, in your Google Cloud console, navigate to Logging for your project.  At the right of the text box for "Filter by label or text search" you will see a small dropdown arrow.  Click that and select "Convert to advanced filter".  This will allow you to write your own sql-ish query where you can find requests that took longer than n to complete.

For example, add the following to the filter:

```
protoPayload.latency>"0.300s"
```

This will return a list of all requests that took longer than 300 milliseconds to process.  If you have Cloud Trace enabled, you can click on the request response time to see the timeline for the individual service calls.